# Springboot: Jar not found exception while running from command line

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, spring-boot

I'm working with a springboot application. While running my app.jar from command line using `java -jar`, I'm getting the following errors

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\MyApp.jar!\lib\jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)

...

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\MyApp.jar!\lib\jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.getResourceIterator(Discoverer.java:298)
    at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discover(Discoverer.java:142)
```

These errors, I'm getting for multiple jars, though the jars are availble in my lib folder under the Spring boot fat jar.

Now, to fix that, I can use [requiresUnpack](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#requiresUnpack), like shown below.

```
          <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version-spring-boot}</version>
        <configuration>
           <requiresUnpack>
              <dependency>
                 <groupId>xxx</groupId>
                 <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                 <groupId>yyy</groupId>
                 <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
              </dependency>
           </requiresUnpack>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <goals>
                 <goal>repackage</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
```

Now, issue with this way is for all my jars, I have add them one by one in my requiresUnpack tag.

But I'm looking for some generic way to do it. Like some one liner, which will fix all of these.SO, is there any way to do it?

---

Edited: Adding other plugins which Im using...

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <configuration>
               <defaultOutputDirectory>
                  ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources
               </defaultOutputDirectory>
               <processors>
                  <processor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</processor>
               </processors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>process</id>
                  <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>process</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                  <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0.0.CR1</version>
               </dependency>
            </dependencies>
         </plugin>
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>add-source</id>
                  <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>add-source</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <sources>
                        <source>target/generated-sources</source>
                     </sources>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
```

These, 2 plugins I'm using for Mapstruct.

Comment: Can you post more of your pom, like al the plugins you have?

Comment: Why not use classic dependency for jackson lib ?

Comment: Its not only with jackson. there are many jars which im getting like this.jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar
jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar
json-patch-1.7.jar
jackson-coreutils-1.6.jar
msg-simple-1.1.jar
btf-1.2.jar
commons-rql-1.0.1.jar
guava-18.0.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar....
... and more

Comment: Sorry to repeat my question but why not use classic dependency and why use repackage ?

Comment: @MickaëlB ok I got u... so what shall I write in goal? can u show me?

Answer (score 0):

As I was saying in comments, why don't use classic dependencies such as :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: no, that i have.. still Im getting this issue! Shall i add the full pom?

Comment: ignore the last comment. yes u are right, if I add the not found jar details in dependencies. Then It will not come.Thnaks for the help. But thouse jars are already availble in my dependency hiererchy and also in lib. so do  manually have to add all these as dependencies. Or there is some other way to solve it?

Comment: From my point of view, this is the right way to do it. I don't know any other solution to do it.

Comment: aahhh!.. actually, when I tried mapping one jar.. it was working. but after adding 2 ints not working? any Idea?

Comment: ignore my last comment!... actually first I added classmate then the not found issue for that jar is gone. then i add jackson-databind. then again not found for both the jars were soing. But now its fine i guess... i clean & build again... now that not found issue is gone